# set checkbox disabled or readonly when its checked

Tags: jquery

Is it possible do set readonly or disabled attribute when the user checked the checkbox ?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox"> Remember me
            </label>
        </div>
  </div>
```

**UPDATE :**

I tried something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input:checkbox[name='checkbox']").change(function() {  
        this.prop('readonly', true);
    });
});
```

Comment: yes it is possible what have you tried?any way how would you enable if it is disable?this way you cant undo the disabled checkbox. just a thought

Comment: i've updated my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/guradio/sp3mn3k4/)

Try this way. But as I have said in comment once you disabled this checkbox there is no way you can enable it again maybe you need to change your approach in doing this.

Use selector `ID` and also use prop `disabled` to disabled checkbox not `readonly`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("#checkbox").change(function() {
     if ($(this).is(':checked')) {//check if checkbox is checked
       $(this).prop('disabled', true)
     }

   });

 });
```

Comment: @LucasFrugier i see happy coding

Comment: @guradio you can enable it again by another event (like clicking a button or selecting another DOM element)

Comment: @LelioFaieta yes what i mean he cant enable it on unchecking the same checkbox. Sorry i wasnt clear on that one. thank you for that one i didnt see that one coming